# Does "argumentative" have negative connotation? If so, what's a more neutral word?

Tags: single-word-requests

It seems  *argument* has a negative connotation, almost like bickering. What about *argumentative*?

How to favorably describe a person who doesn't take things at face value but rather debate on veracity while not being an annoying pedant and such?

Is *skeptical* the right word?

More info on context:

I am looking for a word to use in informal sense in everyday language, may be like in a resume or talking about myself when there is no much room for an explanation of the word I use, while not coming across as snobbish. I did think of *critical thinker* but somehow that sounds too posh and over selling. May be a tangential question could be whether or not it is snobbish.

Comment: *argument* may be positive or negative (it's good to offer a good argument for your point of view), but *argumentative* is always a personality flaw in that it describes a bickering manner.

Comment: Yes, what argument means depends on context but from what I know it is largely seen as a negative thing, may not be in legal and formal systems, but surely in informal contexts. Also in this qna http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47064/whats-the-difference-between-debate-and-argument

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Not always, though, at least not in formal academic writing.

Comment: thePet, No, *argument* has a no negative connotation *per se* -- if that were so, no sensible exchange of views would ever have been possible. It is necessary to say this because the question is based on this incorrect premise.

Comment: We commonly hear (or say) things like "Let's not argue" or "I don't want an argument" or "My arguments with Joan are really straining our relationship." In these cases, "argument" clearly isn't about the "sensible exchange of views." The argument that if "argument" has a negative connotation then no sensible exchange of views would ever have been possible is untenable. Call me skeptical, or disputatious, or whatever you like. I prefer to think of it as "logically rigorous." I understand the more formal definition of "argument," but we must admit its common usage as well.

Comment: *Skeptical* may seem a better choice, but in some quarters it covers obstinate blowhards who don't know the subject they're talking about, and aren't willing to learn. Better perhaps to praise a person's *critical thinking skills*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_thinking

Comment: "Argumentative" is more negative than "argument".  And I'll fight anyone who says different!

Comment: Perhaps something like "critical thinker" would fit, if you're seeking to describe someone in a positive light.

Comment: @RustyTuba I would have upvoted your clever comment if I had the rights.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger As I say in the updated post, I didn't consider critical thinking as it sounded too posh and snobbish to me. May be I am wrong.

Comment: @thePetProjectProgrammer - Critical thinking is currently a "battleground phrase":http://www.austinchronicle.com/daily/news/2012-06-27/gop-opposes-critical-thinking/ However, that does not mean it isn't the best choice for your use. All the possibilities suffer some negative connotation or other, so you'd best make your choice based on the intended audience.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger what you say makes sense.

Comment: I'll say I'm **assertive** in discussing matters of opinion or strategy myself, That keeps me from beng pushy or overly posh, but ensures people know that I'm not some wallflower with nothing to contribute.

Comment: Bolster skeptic with healthy and you have _healty skepticism_. You can be skeptical without being cynical.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about using your idiom, not taking facts at face value? That connotes a thoughtful, intelligent person who will debate the facts if they warrant it.

Comment: I am really looking for one word (or two) but I'll have to accept your suggestion if I don't find that word. Seems good enough.

Comment: another option might be a good debater, although that would place emphasis on your skills in debating, rather than the fact that you will debate. Debate is definitely a nicer word than argue though...

Answer (score 1):

Sadly though, the primary definition of (at least the adjective form) *[argumentative](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/argumentative)* (ODO),

> **1** Given to arguing:
>       *an argumentative child*

and worse still,

> *This is not the same as being argumentative, or arguing just for the sake of arguing.*
>   *Towards the end of my little encounter with Sophie Ward we argue about whether or not she is argumentative.*

is clearly negative sounding, the last two examples suggesting *argumentative* = 'arguing just for the sake of arguing.'

That said, there's also the secondary definition,

> **2** Using or characterized by systematic reasoning:
>   *the highest standards of argumentative rigour.*
>   *The paper then directed all of year 10 to select one question, answer it and discuss the reasons for their answer in an argumentative* <sup>1</sup> *essay.*
>   *If we have spent several class periods introducing conventions of reasoned evidence in argumentative* <sup>2</sup> *writing, we usually look for such features in student papers.*

Therefore, it is context and careful structuring of the sentence that will determine if the author intends to convey a negative connotation. Devoid of a clear contextual support, the connotation is naturally seen as negative, because of its primary definition and because of its relatively more frequent use in a negative sense.

**Do** use *argumentative,* with a clear context in support of a neutral connotation (Examples marked <sup>1, 2</sup> above may help).

Comment: We don't even have to discuss connotation. Some sources are more explicit: (from M-W) : tending to argue : having or showing a tendency to disagree or argue with other people in an angry way

Comment: I updated my question with info on context. Could you help me pick a word?

Comment: @Kris The second definition describes the rules of argument as argumentative rules, which is a different meaning altogether from an argumentative person.  I think saying a person is argumentative is always negative.  'Playing Devil's Advocate' is the only positive alternative I can think of at the moment.

Comment: @MBurke Why do you "think" rather than show? That would help better.

Comment: @Kris Because showing a negative is impossible.  I could spend the whole day giving you examples, but it only takes a single example of someone being praised for being argumentative to prove me wrong.  I can't think of one.  But in that spirit, instead of saying, "I think", I change my wording to "I assert".  Now the onus is on anyone who believes it can be positive to come up with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago while working as a supervisor in a fund-raising effort on behalf of a symphony orchestra, I supervised a difficult employee who misunderstood me when I used the word *argument*. He automatically thought I was accusing him of being argumentative, when in fact I was using the term to describe a line of reasoning he was using. His failure to understand me took me by surprise, and my inadequate ad hoc explanation of how I was using the term resulted in my failure to communicate.

There is no doubt that *argument* can have both a negative denotation and connotation, as in the following uses of the word:

> An argument broke out over whose turn it was to pay for lunch.

Or,

> Why must you turn every discussion into an argument?

Clearly, the word as used above denotes and connotes a bit of unpleasantness, complete with bickering, yelling, accusations flying back and forth, and more.

On the other hand, the word can have a neutral denotation and connotation, as in the following uses of the word:

> The debater's argument was well crafted and supported with logic, persuasive statistics, and a memorable closing sentence.

Or,

> Jim's argument concerning what caused the accident failed to persuade the jurors of the defendant's guilt.

Clearly, the word as used above denotes and connotes a line of reasoning which depends more on a thought process than a verbal free-for-all.

Now the word *debate* can also denote and connote something positive or negative, depending on how it is used. Which of the following uses of *debate* is primarily positive, and which is negative?

> The university's representative in the competition was clearly well trained in the art of debate.
>
> [A mother to her young son] Why must everything I ask you to do turn into a debate?

If you think the first use is positive and the second is negative, I'd agree with you. The former use brings to mind a reasoned, rational, even impassioned argument in the context of the give and take of verbal sparring. The latter brings to mind a stubborn child who finds it difficult simply to do as he is told, without complaining, whining, resisting, and finagling his way out of obeying his mother.

As for a synonymous substitute, I suggest the following, the first group of which lean more towards a negative connotation, while the second group leans more toward a positive connotation:

***NEGATIVE***

> - distrustful
> - cynical
> - calculating
> - contrary
> - irresolute (the product of a failure to come to a conclusion--the "on the one hand, but on the other hand" kind of thinking which is never truly resolved in one's mind, one way or the other)
> - indecisive
> - opinionated
> - rationalization
> - clustering (amassing proofs in one's mind as to why a decision is--or was--a good one)

***POSITIVE***

> - skeptical (your suggestion)
> - questioning
> - reasoned
> - sensible
> - balanced and fair minded
> - balanced
> - reflective (tending automatically to reason things out in one's mind before acting)
> - to weigh in one's mind
> - rumination (mentally "chewing the cud")
> - incredulity (n.); incredulous (adj.)

In conclusion, to argue one's point of view *could* involve some negative and unpleasant interactions, but not necessarily. Similarly, a debate could be characterized by a complete lack of regard for the "rules of the game," rife with snipes, ad hominems, unfounded accusations, and made-up facts. On the other hand, a debate could be reasoned, rational, respectful, and fair; in short, it could take the high road, so to speak, and not the low road of insults, invective, and impromptu inveighing against an "opponent."

Comment: Its kinda funny that there are so many close variants yet none is completely positive. May be time to import a word?

Comment: @thePetProjectProgrammer on the contrary there are quite a few with positive connotations. Perhaps rhetorician could list *only* the more positive ones.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Your wish is my command. Don

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but I can't see using any of these in describing a person the way I intend to in a way that would immediately convey my intentions, except may be skeptical which is mine lol. Thanks again.

Comment: thePetProjectProgrammer:  That's OK. Then how about incredulity? He was characterized as a man of natural incredulity. Adjectival form: incredulous. I'll add it to my list, above. Don

Answer (score 1):

How about "counterargumentative"? While it is ad-hoc from counterargument (typically used in the context of reasoned debate), since you want something informal, that might be desirable.

A more formal term would be rhetorician:

> rhetorician
>
> *noun*
>
> an expert in formal rhetoric.

Edit:

After reading and thinking about this a bit more, I think the connotation really starts to come down to your ideology. In one such philosophy, known as Sophism, students learned to dispute their opponent no matter what, using an "eristic" argument. Plato and others were staunchly opposed to this methodology, and instead preferred the "dialectic". That full discussion is likely out of the scope of the question though. In any case, I'd like to add "dialectical", from my point of view.

> dialectical
>
> *adjective*
>
> 1.
> relating to the logical discussion of ideas and opinions.
>
> 2.
> concerned with or acting through opposing forces.

Edit:

You might also simply describe yourself as *a debater*.

Comment: The answer would be improved with the addition of dictionary references for the chosen words.

Answer (score 0):

A word you may wish to consider, in place of ***argumentative*** is ***discursive***. Its main sense means roughly the same thing, but doesn't convey the idea of a difficult mindset. There is a problem in that it does have an alternative sense (2 below) with suggests a tendency to digression and to move around from one aspect to another - "in rapid or irregular manner".

1. Examples from 1555 but only more recent ones below.

   > 1. Of or characterized by reasoned argument or thought; logical, ratiocinative. Often opposed to intuitive.

> 1876   L. Stephen Hours in
>
> Libr. 2nd Ser. v. 218   Johnson..is always a man of intuitions rather
> than of discursive intellect.
>
> 1929   Jrnl. Philos. Stud. 4 248   The
> dianoetic logic..comprehends the purely formal connections of concepts
> in the judgments and the discursive procedure of thought.>
>
> 1961   M.
> Esslin Theatre of Absurd 17   The open abandonment of rational devices
> and discursive thought.>
>
> 2007   J. McCourt Now Voyagers xi. 515   The
> only legitimate laws are those that can be rationally accepted by
> everyone in a discursive process of opinion and will formation.

2. Examples from 1599 - but only more recent ones shown.

> 2 a. That passes from one subject to another, esp. in a rapid or
> irregular manner; extending over or dealing with a wide range of
> subjects; expansive; digressive. In later use (e.g. quot. 2001)
> sometimes: framed as a discourse or as connected prose, non-technical;
> cf. discoursive adj.
>
> 1867   E. A. Freeman Hist. Norman Conquest I. iv. 166   A most vivid,
> though very discursive and garrulous, history of the time.
>
> 1904   Outlook 24 Sept. 241/2   A pleasingly discursive talk about the
> haunts and homes of Burns.
>
> 1930   Economist 3 May 1007/2   The directors conclude a somewhat
> discursive report with remarks upon the wastefulness of sterilised
> gold.
>
> 1973   Ethnomusicology 17 42   He showed himself to be..a discursive
> but lively table-talker.
>
> 2001   I. J. Deary Intelligence v. 99   These papers are technical
> along the way, but the discursive sections are written with laudable
> clarity.